# Labview Linear Fit alternative?

Tags: statistics, labview

In the process of calibrating a tool, we need to find the best line fit for three data points. LabVIEW has a nice Linear Fit.vi tool, but unfortunately that is only part of the Full Development System. This would cost $3000 that our small company can ill afford, just for one library VI. I wonder, has anyone out there written a good alternative bit of line-fitting code that would be willing to share it?

Comment: Linear regression is pretty easy to calculate yourself. Here is a good guide I used just the other day for some other stuff.

https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-regression.php

Comment: Suggestion: contact your NI field sales engineer... sometimes much cheaper deals can be negotiated if you just need a library or two.